# Ubuntu 11.10 Classic Desktop opens all windows twice with same

Tags: panel

All programs (incl Internet) appear twice in the bottom panel, once you close one tab, both close. How can I get this fixed? Thanx a lot in advance

Comment: I guess u've added the indicator applet twice.. either delete the applet or delete the panel and then recreate the panel !

Answer (score 0):

You got a dupe panel.

Just means its being displayed twice. So... easiest way is to delete the panel and make a new one, use the alt combo (I think its alt... might be control)

So after you delete it, make a new one. Combo the desktop and click "Add panel" 
then combo the panel and "Add to panel" and I believe its called "notification area"

If you got dual monitors, however, there might be another reason... but on 11.10, iunno.